# Saving project properties in SoapUI's groovy

Tags: command-line, groovy, properties, soapui

Here is my problem. I'm running TestRunner from command line in order not to launch SoapUI client. (anyway, same problem occurs when running TR straight from client, so not sure if worth mentioning but anyways...). I do it this way:

> ```
> testrunner <path_to_project> -r -a -f <path_to_reports> & pause
> ```

In one of my TC I retrieve data from DB, then save it to project properties this way:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("key", value);
```

Then I use it in next steps which **works fine**. The problem appears in other TC where, **firstly**, I get filename from my project properties, this way:

```
def oldFilename = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("FILE_NAME");
```

Then I want to use it, rename it and save to project properties again, so that it would be ready for next launch. I do it the same way:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("FILE_NAME", newFilename);
```

It seems to be not saving/storing this value. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify anything in your project, and you want to preserve that from one run to the next, use the `-S` (uppercase) switch.

[Documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html#1-testrunner-description-of-parameters) is your friend. :)