# SoapUI: Why Project properties are not updating when i run all tests with Testrunner

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have some problem with updating of project properties in SoapUI when i run all tests in my project with "Launch TestRunner".

I have two TestSuites with tests. All TestCases have first step - groovy script. This script the same in all TestCases:

```
Integer curIdAndKey = new Integer (testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "IdAndKey" ))
Boolean curBool = new Boolean (testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "bool" ))
Integer curTestsCount =new Integer( testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "countOfTests" ))
if(curBool==false){
    curBool=true
    curIdAndKey= curIdAndKey*curTestsCount
}
else {
    curIdAndKey += 1
}

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("aIdCase", curIdAndKey.toString())
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("bool", curBool.toString())
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("IdAndKey", curIdAndKey.toString())
log.info "Current Id : [$curIdAndKey]"
log.info "Current bool : [$curBool]"
```

And i have a project properties: "IdAndKey" and "bool".
When i run single TestCase - this project properties are updating, but when i run all my tests, they are not updating (i see updating only in log, but not in properties). 
Please, help me.

Comment: Already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26460598/3124333

Comment: No, it's not the same. I need to run tests from SoapUI, not from command line.

Comment: You said: ... with "Launch TestRunner". That makes it the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options on the Launch TestRunner window, under the Basic tab, is: "Save After". Select this option and press Launch. You will notice that the `-S` switch (discussed in the linked duplicate post) is added to the command line, which is shown on the next window.

Additional discussion, although outdated, is in the [official docs](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/launch-testrunner.html).

Comment: My project property IdAndKey is steel the same, it's changes visible only in logs, but after tests runnig value the same:(

Comment: Close and open the project.

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but is there any other way without closing and opening project?

Comment: What you are doing does not sound like normal workflow. If you could describe what is it that you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
def globalProps = context.testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;
globalProps.setPropertyValue("aIdCase", curIdAndKey.toString());
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: In my case it works, I also use some global props, and I save them in the project proprieties.